# How to make the position of divs fixed so they don't change on when resizing?

Tags: html, css, sass, positioning, bootstrap-4

I'm making a layout for Tic Tac Toe game, therefore I want the square blocks to stay always in the same position when the screen is being resized.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and SCSS.

1) How can i make them fixed in the same position no matter what the
    screen size is?

2) If the screen size gets smaller, how can i resize
        all the items inside the game-wrapper div depending on screen size?

codepen link : https://codepen.io/Jaunbruns/pen/pwXaRP?editors=1100

HTML:

```css
.block {
  background-color: lightBlue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  &:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="game-wrap">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
      <div class="block"> </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use: *pixel* sizes and *relative* sizes using *mediaqueries*.

You will use pixels for *fixed* position and *relative* sizes when you are in small screens.